# Edit object in sub of sub array in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I need update a sub of sub array in MongoDB.

My Document:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5433d63cfafed42c083e0809"),
    "name" : "Flavio",
    "desc" : "feature", 
    "US" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("543ebeb473bc8d243d6b28dc"),
            "name" : "asdf",
            "desc" : "asdf", 
            "tasks" : [
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("544029257266e4841735cde8"),
                    "name" : "hello",
                    "date" : "16/10/2014 05:23:01 pm",
                    "author" : "5424ac37eb0ea85d4c921f8b"
                },
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("54410bf33561315021a29e2b"),
                    "name" : "lol",
                    "date" : "17/10/2014 09:30:43 am",
                    "author" : "5424ac37eb0ea85d4c921f8b"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I need push a new array to task of US.tasks._id = ObjectId("54410bf33561315021a29e2b").

the task updated expected:

```
{
   "_id" : ObjectId("54410bf33561315021a29e2b"),
   "name" : "lol",
   "date" : "17/10/2014 09:30:43 am",
   "author" : "5424ac37eb0ea85d4c921f8b"
   "points" : [
       {
           "count" : 10,
           "name": "pt"
       }
   ]
}
```

I Trying with:

```
db.projects.update({
    "US.tasks": {
            $elemMatch: {"_id": ObjectId("544029257266e4841735cde8")}
    }
}, {
    $push: {"US.$.tasks": {"points" : []}} 
})


db.projects.update({
    "US.tasks": {
            $elemMatch: {"_id": ObjectId("544029257266e4841735cde8")}
    }
}, {
    $push: {"US.$.tasks.points": {"count" : 10, "name" : "pt"}} 
})
```

But the new objects not enter in task object.

How i fix that and get my expected object?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is another way to do that

```
db.projects.find(
{
    "US.tasks": {$elemMatch: {"_id": ObjectId("544029257266e4841735cde8")}}
}).forEach(function(item)
{
    var us = item.US;    

    for (var i = 0; i < item.US.length; i++) 
        {            
            var tasks = item.US[i].tasks;
            for (var i2 = 0; i2 < tasks.length; i2++) 
                {
                    var task = tasks[i2];
                    var id = task._id;                   

                    if(id == "544029257266e4841735cde8")
                    {
                        // add new filed
                        task.pointse = {};                        
                        break;
                    }                    
                }
         }

    db.projects.save(item);         
});
```